# How do I get email notifications post reply from Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, user-accounts, notifications, email

I thought that I could set Ask Ubuntu to send me email notifications when one of my posts was answered, but now it doesn't, and I'm wondering if there's some way to enable that feature. Thanks!

Comment: You only get an email if you haven't already checked your site notifications, and the frequency of emails can be adjusted, or emails can be turned off altogether, in your profile settings (on your user page, click on edit profile and settings, then email settings, and see which option you have set there). Do either of these things explain your situation? Does think linked question and its answer (and the comments on the answer) help you?